# Confusion about interior of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$\mathbb{Z}$ is *nowhere dense* in $\mathbb{R}$ since $Int(\overline{Z}) = \emptyset$. However, I am having a hard time seeing that the interior of $\overline{Z}$ is truly empty.

Consider $A \subset \mathbb{Z}$ as $A = \{1,2,3\}$. Then, $\overline{A} = A$ since $A' = \emptyset$. Then, I want to say that $Int(\overline{A}) = \{2\} \neq \emptyset$ since there is an epsilon ball $B_{\epsilon}(2) \subset A$.

But, $\mathbb{Z}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so that includes any subset of $\mathbb{Z}$.

What is my error here?

Comment: $B_\epsilon(2)$ isn't contained in $A$, since it contains some noninteger $2+\delta$ for some small $\delta$.

Comment: Is that still true if we remove $\mathbb{R}$ from this scenario?

Comment: If you remove $\Bbb R$... well, it depends. Interior is not an intrinsic definition. It heavily depends on the ambient space.

Answer (score 5):

Do you think that $A$ can really contain a ball ? (i.e. that $B_\varepsilon(2)\cap A^c=\emptyset$ for an $\varepsilon>0$ ?)

[image]

Comment: I suppose not if we are considering $A \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$. However, if we are taking the integers without thought of $\mathbb{R}$, then wouldn't $\mathbb{Z}^{c}$ be empty, in which case $B_{\epsilon}(2) \subset A$?

Comment: @clocktower If we are considering $A$ as a subset of $\Bbb Z$ and not of $\Bbb R$, then _everything changes_. In fact, $\Bbb Z$ is a dense subset of $\Bbb Z$. As G. Sassatelli mentions in a different comment, it _all_ depends on the ambient space.

Answer (score 1):

You should remark that $\mathbb{Z}$ is actually a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. (For example take the complementary).

Hence $\overline{\mathbb{Z}} = \mathbb{Z},$ which will simplify your proof.